# Google Analytics Manage user permission issue

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to add my service account to users which requires manage user permission. Under View User Management it says for my User

**Collaborate, Read & Analyse, Manage Users**

But when click on Account User Management to add my service accoint it says

You have access to this account, but you don't have permission to manage this account's users. Without user management permissions, you cannot add/remove users or change other users' permissions. To manage this account's users, one of this account's administrators must grant you user management permissions.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved  the issue after checking the level of permission i have. I found out I did not have any Account Level Permission but does have View and Property level permission to add users/service account.

So I click *Property User Management* under Property tab and add my service as user.

[image: Admin Page]